# Validate excel spread sheet format in MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We are accepting excel files from user to upload in our application (MVC4) and I would like to know is there any better approach to validate the excel spreadsheet format? I need to validate the format of the excel and also the data in the spread sheet before I accept the file and upload to our server.

Comment: A better approach than what? How are you currently validating it?

Comment: Just getting started  on this and we are looking @ validating the spread sheet using XSD. But that's a very old way of doing. Just wanted to know if there is any better way ?

Comment: You cant do any validation in the browser (except to check the file extension) so it has to be uploaded to the server first. But what sort of validation are you wanting to do?

Comment: Format of the excel file and make sure excel file has all the columns we are expecting...

Comment: You could use [Open Office SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)